# pass $_POST variables from HTML-email to webpge

Tags: html, forms, email, gmail

I am trying to pass some variables from an email message (which I generate) to a webpage.

The HTML body of my email message (which I am opening in Gmail) contains a button like this:

```
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/vars.php">   
   <input type="hidden" name="artist" value="x" />
   <input type="hidden" name="title_work" value="y" />
   <input type="hidden" name="genre" value="z" />
   <input type="submit" value="CLICK HERE" />                       
</form>
```

But when on vars.php I echo `$_POST` I get nothing.

Comment: include the portnumber in the action url. works for me

Comment: thanks @AjumobiOlamide could you give me an example? I've never included a port number

Comment: "htttp://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .":". $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ."/vars.php" gets the url with the port number

Comment: ah I get it now... I'll try, thanks